# Interpolation warp

Tags: c++, opencv, interpolation

I use opencv with cpp.

I have `std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point2d, cv::Point2d> >` wich represent a warp.
For each point of an image A, i associate a point of an image B. 
I don't know all association between points of image A and points of image B. The points of image A are on a sparse matrix. These data have also probably epsilon error.
So I would like interpolate.
In opencv I don't found a function which do simply an interpolation.
How do this ?

I found the function [cv::warpPoint](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/warpers.html#detail-rotationwarper-warppoint) but I don't know the `cv::Mat` Camera intrinsic parameters nor `cv::Mat` Camera rotation matrix.
How compute these matrix from my data ?

Comment: try  `cv::getPerspectiveTransform` with your point pairs in separated vectors followed by a `cv::warpPerspective` if your warps can be represented by a perspective homography.

Comment: My image A is distorded so it isn't a simple perspective.

Comment: Are the warp points scattered or regular?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is piecewise affine warper:

https://code.google.com/p/imgwarp-opencv/

I have my own fast implementation, but comments are in russian, you can find it [here](https://github.com/Smorodov/FaceRotate).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand better with the edit. But what do you want to say with de step 4 ?

Comment: Is it the same idea that your first ?

Comment: No, that's not the same idea. I've remeber the problem I've bump then implemented warping method. It was when you scan souce pixels destination point coordiantes you get did not match with pixels coordiantes (integer values). That's why I've implemented inverse warp, when you set destination pixel value and get source pixel value coordinates. In the implementation above I've used barycentric interpolation (that's why point set need triangulation). In regular grid you can set triangles by hardcoding (not need triangulator).

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 questions:

1. how to warp the points from one image to the other. 
   Try `cv::remap` to do that, once you have dense (interpolated) description. See http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html for example.
2. How to compute non-given point pairs by interpolation.
   I don't have a solution for this, but some ideas:

   - don't use point pairs but displacement vectors. displacement might be easier to interpolate.
   - use inverse formulation to get a dense description of the second image (otherwise there might be pixel that aren't touched at all

But I guess the "real" method to do this would be some kind of spline interpolation.

Comment: I don't understand your ideas for the interpolation. displacement vector is got by : point Bi - point Ai ? What formulation ?

Comment: I have another idea. What do you think about this ? I construct a cv::Mat in which each point has as value his coordinates. Then I map this image with my warp.

Comment: ok so your displacement is exactly what my displacement would be. I thought you'd use the "pairs" as elements in your matrix.

Comment: to fill empty elements in a sparse Mat I've seen a method: downscale your image by halfwhere the pixel value is the mean of all set values in the higher resolutions neighborhood. do this until your mat is only 1x1 pixel sized. Then upsample again and fill the holes in your layer with the value of the downsampled layer at that position. But I don't know whether this interpolation will lead to good results here.